# Issue rendering partial with collection in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Having an issue rendering this partial collection in rails. There's no error message, it simply won't display on the show view. However, if I manually loop through the @page_forum.comments collection (example below), it will work. I'm wanting the partials to work since I'm planning on using AJAX functionality. For context, I just want a forum topic (page_forum) to display its associated comments.

Any advice is appreciated!

The comment partial:

```
app>views>comments/_comment.html.erb

    <h3><%= comment.title %></h3>
    <p><%=comment.body%></p>
    <p><%=comment.user.username%></p>
```

app>views>page_forums>show.html.erb

This works:

```
<% @page_forum.comments.each do |c| %>
    <%= c.body%>
<% end %>
```

This does not work (but I want it to):

```
<% render partial: 'comments/comment', collection: @page_forum.comments %>
```

Comment model:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :page_forum
end
```

PageForum model:

```
class PageForum < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :page
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments
end
```

Also the server logs are saying the collection was rendered:

```
Rendered collection of comments/_comment.html.erb [1 times] (Duration: 3.7ms | Allocations: 908)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.  You missed the `=` which "shows" the result of the code.

```
<%= render partial: 'comments/comment', collection: @page_forum.comments %>
```